# How to set changing=true on versionCatalogs in gradle

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, nexus3

We have a in-house versionCatalog on our Nexus repository, and now (in development phase of the project) it is changing frequently.

In our projects `settings.gradle` we have following block:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        libs {
            from("com.myCompany.myGroup:catalog:latest.release")
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is although it has `latest.release` version, it is cached for a while (I think 24 hours).

I tried to add `changing=true` to this, but no chance... so is there any way I can force gradle to get **just this dependency** on every build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a snapshot repository, and published my released there. Then I have changed `latest:release` to `latest:integration`, and it (almost) worked as I expected.